# SDL Saving window as BMP

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, sdl

I am writing a program in `SDL` and `C` and I want to be able to save the window as an image.

This is my code:

```
screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);
SDL_SaveBMP(screen,"screen");
```

But when I execute it I get:

```
Segmentation Fault
```

From other sources I gather that its about pointers and memory access. Any help?

Comment: Have you seen this? - https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromMem

Answer (score 4):

```
    SDL_Surface *sshot = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 750, 750, 32, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff, 0xff000000);
    SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, NULL, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, sshot->pixels, sshot->pitch);
    SDL_SaveBMP(sshot, "screenshot.bmp");
    SDL_FreeSurface(sshot);
```

Comment: Don't you need to lock `sshot`?

Answer (score 2):

Call [SDL_LockSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockSurface) on a window surface before saving bitmap, and SDL_UnlockSurface after that.

Comment: Tried your solution but it seems screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);returns NULL