# SDL2 C++ Capturing Video of Renderer Animation/Sprite

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, sdl, sdl-2

I have an animation/sprite created using SDL2. The animation works fine when it is being rendered to a screen. But now I also want it to be recorded into a video file (locally stored). For this, I am planning on using FFmpeg APIs, to which I'll be sending a raw RGB pixel data array.

My problem is with fetching the data from SDL2 APIs.

What I've tried is:

```
// From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157164/sdl-saving-window-as-bmp
SDL_Surface *sshot = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 750, 750, 32, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff, 0xff000000);
SDL_RenderReadPixels(gRenderer, NULL, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, sshot->pixels, sshot->pitch);

// From https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromMem
char fName[50];
sprintf(fName, "/tmp/a/ss%03d.bmp", fileCnt);


char bitmap[310000];
SDL_RWops *rw = SDL_RWFromMem(bitmap, sizeof(bitmap));
SDL_SaveBMP_RW(sshot, rw, 1);
```

Above does not work. But dumping a single frame into a file with following code works:

`SDL_SaveBMP(sshot, "/tmp/alok1/ss.bmp")`

This obviously is not an acceptable solution - Writing to thousands of BMPs and then using FFmpeg from command-line to create a video.

What am I doing wrong? How do you extract data from [SDL_RWops](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops)? Is the use of [SDL_RWFromMem](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromMem) the right approach to my problem statement?

Comment: `750*750*4` is more than `310000`. Your buffer is too small. (you'll need `width*height*bpp` + BMP header bytes, at least)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you very much for pointing that out. I'd calculated it to be close to 2.5MB, and to be on a safe side, i wanted to allocate 3MB. Missed a zero there. I can accept this as an answer if you'd post it as such. If you think it's too trivial, I'll delete the question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffer is too small to fit specified image, hence it cannot be saved here. Increase buffer size to at least actual image size + BMP header (`width*height*bpp` + 54, but padding needs to be counted too (what SDL_Surface refers as `pitch`)).

Note that taking 3Mb from stack may get you dangerously close to overflow (but could still be fine, depends on what happened in functions prior to the one in question). Chain-calling several functions that takes big chunk of stack may very quickly deplete it. It is likely you don't really need any extra space or BMP conversion at all - like creating AVImage and copying pixels directly to it from SDL_Surface.

Also in terms of performance this kind of readback would not be great (but probably compression itself is much heavier anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the additional performance tip. I'll change the sizes right away. Additionally, I'm allocating 3MB, and freeing it after use, in a loop, from a single-threaded application. 3MB is allowed in my environment, but could it still overflow? Also, after all modules are completed, this array would be replaced by one of FFmpeg's structured as you've suggested. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, if your stack is e.g. 4 Mb (or 8 on some platforms), you can freely use up to that amount. But if you have a function that takes several megs of stack and calls another function that calls another function, ..., each taking big arrays on stack - it could overflow (recursive functions manages overflow even with allocating tiny amount, but with huge number of nested calls). But you know your code better, if it is not the case and this function is not called deep in call chain, then it might be completely ok.

Comment: I'll need some time to process this coming from a Java background, and not exactly having mastered there either :) I better get this reviewed from an expert. Thanks again for all the help.